# What is required of me to implement to be able to add new items to a tableViewController from another viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to learn iOS development but have stalled a bit so I hope that there is some kind soul here who might be able to help me in the right direction.

Let's say I have a UITableViewController that displays a number of items, consisting of a title and subtitle ( Subtitle style of a Tableview Cell). Items.m/h only consist of two properties, title and subtitle and a init method to set the properties. In my app delegate i create some default items and pass them/set them to my tableViewController's property tvc.items, which is a NSMutableArray. What do I need to do / what components do I need, to be able to add more items and then display them in my tableViewController?

I started with the following:

1. Added a new view controller in the storyboard
2. Embeddade the viewController in a Navigation Controller
3. Added a Bar Button Item at my Table View Controller with an identifier of add
4. Ctrl + drag from BarButtonItem (add) to my new view controller selected modal segue
5. Created a new class AddNewItemViewController
6. Entered this as the class under the Identity Inspector for the new view controller
7. I then added two Bar Button Items, Cancel and Done (with cancel and done as identifiers) in the storyboard for the new View Controller
8. This was followed by me adding two UITextFields, one for the Title and one for the Subtitle
9. Ctrl + drag from these outlets into AddNewItemViewController.m, between @interface AddNewItemViewController () ... here ...@end (so they become Private? Should I drag it here or to AddNewItemViewController.h ?, What is the standard way for doing similar outlets?).
10. In AddNewItemViewController I added two properties, NSString's (nonatomic, copy) * title and *subtitle which I thought would keep the input data from an intended user.

So, after this I now want do two things, and it is here as it becomes difficult (for me at least):

1. Making so that by clicking on Cancel, one return to the Table View controller, ie a dismissed the modal .
2. Adding the data within the text fields to that NSMutableArray which is the datasource by clicking Done.

So what is required of me to do the last two steps? 
Where should I ctrl + drag from the Cancel and Done (so there will be actions)? I guess they must be submitted to AddNewItemViewController.m, but what must be done to dismiss the modal (by clicking on the 'Cancel') and what should be called at or performed when clicking on 'Done'? 
Which or what class (es) must know about the other class?
Last but not least, what should I send in the prepareForSegue call (which I guess I will need to have to use to send the input data back to the table view controller)?

Where to start and what methods should i learn about in order to achieve my mission?

Best Regards,
Rookie

Comment: Man you wrote so much in this question, where to start answering

Comment: @meda Yeah, sorry... Perhaps answer my last question: Where i should start and what methods i should learn about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

much quesetions :)
I will beginn with the close action.
Have a look at the AppleDocumentation, dismissViewController with sender self (your AddViewController).

To store your data from AddViewController to your TableViewController, it's a better way to use delegation.

AddViewController.h

```
@protocol AddViewControllerDelegate;

@interface AddViewController : UIViewController

      @property (nonatomic, weak) id<AddViewControllerDelegate>delegate;

@end

@protocol AddViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) addViewControllerDidFinishTakingData:(AddViewController *)addViewController      withTitle:(NSString *)title andSubtitle:(NSString *)subTitle;


@end
```

AddViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    NSString *title = ...;
    NSString *subtitle = .. .;

    [self.delegate addViewControllerDidFinishTakingData:self withTitle:title andSubtitle:subtitle];
```

}

TableViewController.m

```
@interface TableViewController ()<AddViewControllerDelegate>


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourIdentifier"])
    {
          AddViewController *addViewController = (AddViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
          addViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Last but not least to implement your new delegate-method

```
- (void)addViewControllerDidFinishTakingData:(AddViewController *)addViewController withTitle:(NSString *)title andSubtitle:(NSString *)subTitle
  {
        // handle your data here (store to array)
        // reload your table
  }
```

Better way, to create a Class (Model) for every entry.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to assign tvc.items to the destinationViewController's property during prepareForSegue.

You are correct in thinking that the Cancel and Done buttons belong to the AddNewItemViewController.

In the action for Done, you could add the new item to the items array you passed in during prepareForSegue, then in the presenting view controller (the one you launched the modal from), during viewDidAppear just reload the table. It'll be called when the modal disappears.